Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system (ubuntu 24.04 )
I am installing awsclientvpn (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/client-vpn-connect-linux.html) on my new ubuntu 24.04 machine.
When i try to execute the application i get the following error message:

Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the
system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to
true if you want to run with no globalization support.    at
System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)    at
System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()    at
System.TimeZoneInfo.GetDisplayName(TimeZoneDisplayNameType,
System.String ByRef)    at System.TimeZoneInfo..ctor(Byte[],
System.String, Boolean)    at
System.TimeZoneInfo.GetTimeZoneFromTzData(Byte[], System.String)    at
System.TimeZoneInfo.GetLocalTimeZoneFromTzFile()    at
System.TimeZoneInfo+CachedData.CreateLocal()    at
System.CurrentSystemTimeZone..ctor()    at
System.TimeZone.get_CurrentTimeZone()    at GLib.Marshaller..cctor()
at GLib.Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup(System.String)    at
GLib.Global.set_ProgramName(System.String)    at
Gtk.Application.SetPrgname()    at Gtk.Application.Init()    at
ACVC.GTK.Program.Initialize()    at
ACVC.GTK.Program.Main(System.String[]) [1]    79066 IOT instruction
(core dumped)  "/opt/awsvpnclient/AWS VPN Client"

ChatGPT Sugguested installing sudo apt-get install libicu-dev which i already have.
Then i suggested setting DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT which worked.
export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1
"/opt/awsvpnclient/AWS VPN Client"

I am just wondering if there is a different package i need to install on ubuntu 24.04 to get the valid ICU package.
